# Let users access account before confirming email address

Tags: emails, users

I'd like to let users access their account without confirming email address. But still send the email confirmation. Then I'll display a message saying that if email is not confirmed within 3 days, account will be deleted. How can I do this in drupal 7 ? Is there any module that can help me do this, or if I need to do it in my custom module, please give me a hint about how can this be done ? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by help of [LoginToboggan](https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module. There are so many features of this module, immediate login is one of them.

Comment: You can definitely do this with LoginToboggan but the module is fairly buggy (take a look at the issue queue).  It's not a showstopper; I use LoginToboggan on one of my sites and it's a great help. Just make sure you carefully test what you're trying to do.

Comment: @PatrickKenny - I agree with you about buggy but it's great start for so many situation related to signup/login

Comment: Thank you Rajeev. Exactly what I was looking for. However, I still have a problem and may be you can help me with this as well. I need to change the user role when he confirm his email address. Means that, he register, access his account with email confirmation still pending, but when he confirms, change his role so that he get access to other part of the website. How would you do that ?

Comment: @IAVarsally - Check Rules module for doing this. Assign role when he confirm mail...

Comment: I've been fighting with rules for the past two hours, lol. The problem is that there is no such event as "When user confirms email" or "On Email Confirmation" in rules. I've been looking for a way to know if the user has confirm his email or not, but nothing yet.

Comment: Check this - https://drupal.org/node/628334#comment-6894930

Comment: Check a event named "When the user account is validated" in new rule set. It should be there if LogginToBoggan is enabled...

Comment: Well, I was about to break my keyboard. I followed your instructions Rajeev but couldn't make it work because the confirmation url sent to the user was wrong, it was [user:one-time-login-url] but it should be [user:validate-url]. See https://drupal.org/node/2003778#comment-7463486. Anyway, I finally got this working, thank you very much Rajeev.

Comment: @IAVarsally - It worked at the end & thats all matter now right :)